# Cant run binary file although architectures match

Tags: executable, binary

I have to run a binary file I have downloaded from [here](https://www.roboti.us/getid/getid_linux) but when I execute:

`sudo bash getid_linux`

I get:

`getid_linux: getid_linux: cannot execute binary file`

If I run:

`file getid_linux`

I get:

`getid_linux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=bc6141bc99d3890cb291f010c92edbb59a0dbf37, not stripped`

I think it is not an architecture problem with my Ubuntu installation (which is running on a virtual machine), since if I run:

`uname -a`

I get:

`Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you run `chmod +x` on the file before trying to run it?

Comment: You should not attempt to use `bash` to execute a binary executable. Just call it by name, giving the path if it is not located in a directory that's already on your `PATH` e.g. `./getid_linux`

Comment: I tried that. But I got that I don't have permissions, so I wrote `sudo ./getid_linux` and I got that that command does not exist :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `chmod +x` before solved it, as it was pointed out by [Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1) in the comments

Comment: I run `chmod +x ./getid_linux` first, then run `./getid_linux` works